# How to use video filters (cropdetect) with ffprobe

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, ffprobe

Checking the [ffprobe docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe-all.html#cropdetect) apparently there is an option to use `cropdetect` with it. I am already aware that I could do this with `ffmpeg` like:

```
ffmpeg -ss 900 -i "foo.mkv" -vframes 100 -vf cropdetect -f null - 2>&1
```

but I'd like to do it with `ffprobe` simply because I'm trying to use this in a bash script, I have a bunch of ifs and elses depending on quality and format of the input before composing the final ffmpeg command and I want to leverage the json output from `ffprobe`

Regardless of what ever I tried I cannot use any of the video filters listed in documentation, and there are no examples listed there either. Does anyone know how to run a similar cropdetect filter with `ffprobe`?

I had some luck with:

```
ffprobe -f lavfi -i "movie=foo.mkv,cropdetect" -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time:frame_tags -print_format json
```

But this seemingly print cropdetect for every frame in the video.

Answer (score 0):

set `packet_tags`.

```
ffprobe -f lavfi -i movie=foo.mkv,cropdetect -show_entries packet_tags=lavfi.cropdetect.x1,lavfi.cropdetect.x2,lavfi.cropdetect.y1,lavfi.cropdetect.y2,lavfi.cropdetect.w,lavfi.cropdetect.h,lavfi.cropdetect.x,lavfi.cropdetect.y -print_format json
```

Comment: Hi @nico_lab I added `lavfi` there just as a last resort, is there no other way to just provide this cropdetect (or any other video filter listed in that documentation) to ffprobe?

Comment: this btw just adds on to the format.. it changes nothing in the example commands i gave.

Comment: You can change the acquisition time with -read_intervals. https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe-all.html#Main-options
Other filters can handle the return value as it is, such as metadata, drawgraph, and drawtext filters.
I'm not good at programming, so I can't show you command examples.

Comment: Since you are taking packet metadata, you can add -show_entries packet.
```ffprobe -v error -f lavfi -i color=white,fillborders=0:0:32:16:2,cropdetect -select_streams v:0 -show_entries packet_tags=lavfi.cropdetect.x1,lavfi.cropdetect.x2,lavfi.cropdetect.y1,lavfi.cropdetect.y2,lavfi.cropdetect.w,lavfi.cropdetect.h,lavfi.cropdetect.x,lavfi.cropdetect.y -show_entries packet -of json```